# How to display number values with commas in form

Tags: ms-access, format, vba

In my Access query, I have the query using a VBA function to figure the value that goes in the query field.

In the form, if the stringval textbox has a value, then I want to compute it, but if not, it should remain empty (null).

```
Function GetValue(stringval, numval)
    Dim result
    stringval= stringval & ""
    result= IIf(stringval<> "", numval* 1.5, Null)
    GetValue = Int(result)
End Function
```

Now, I have a form that uses this query, and on the form is a textbox that displays the query value.  I want the value to be formatted with commas in the numbers for easy reading.  Everything I've tried so far does not show any commas.

I've tried:

- used `Standard` for the `Format > Format`for the textbox (in properties)
- putting `#,###.###` in the textbox Format value
- putting `#,##0.0##` in the textbox Format value
- changing `Data > Text Format` but it only gives me `Plain Text` and `Rich Text` - no option for numbers.
- returning a double from the function

Note: if I don't use a custom VBA function, and write the formula directly into the query, then it does display commas.  But when I move the formula into the function then the commas are lost.

What do I do?

*[update]*

I tried Gustav's solutions and since they didn't work for me, I added those as items to my "what I've tried" list above.

Also, if I look at the query in datasheet view, the number values sort alphabetically instead of by the size of the value.  When I used the forumulae directly in the query instead of using functions, it sorted by the value of the number.  I hope this is a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is this:  the function has to be declared as a `double`.

That allows the query's datasheet view to know it is displaying numbers - and so you can set the field's format to `Standard` for the comma to display.  This also allows the form to know it has a number and it will display the comma there, too.  I knew it had to do with `double`, but didn't realize before that the function needed to be declared as such.

```
Function GetValue(stringval, numval) as double '<----THIS!!!!
    Dim result
    If stringval & "" <> "" Then
        result = numval * 1.5
    Else
        result = 0  `<--can't return null here; use nz function in control source for textbox
    End If
    GetValue = int(result) 'to remove decimals
End Function
```

The problem I was having was in some of my functions I need to return `double` or `null`, because I wanted textboxes to remain blank if they contained no data.  Now, at least I know how to make the numbers generated by functions to display commas.

And here is how to deal with the fact that you can't return null as the value of a double. [The function is originally from here](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/189547-hiding-zero-values-text-boxes).

Put this function in a module so it is public, and then in the `control source` for the textbox, instead of just putting the field value, put `Zn(fieldvalue)`.  This works like a charm (although using functions in the `control source` seems to have a delay on the form display).  This way you can keep the underlying value as a `double` and still get commas to display in both the form and the query whilst keeping the field blank if necessary.

```
Public Function Zn(pvar)
' Return null if input is zero or ""
    If IsNull(pvar) Then
        Zn = Null
    ElseIf IsNumeric(pvar) Then
        If pvar = 0 Then
            Zn = Null
        Else
            Zn = pvar
        End If
    Else
        If Len(pvar) = 0 Then
            Zn = Null
        Else
            Zn = pvar
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Numbers carries no format. A format is applied when displayed only.

But be sure to return a Double if not Null:

```
Function GetValue(stringval, numval)

    Dim result

    If stringval & "" <> "" Then
        result = Int(CDbl(numval) * 1.5)
    Else
        result = Null
    End If

    GetValue = result

End Function
```

Then apply your Format to the textbox

```
#,##0.0##
```

Or force a formatted string to be returned:

```
    If stringval & "" <> "" Then
        result = Format(Int(CDbl(numval) * 1.5), "#,##0.0##")
    Else
        result = Null
    End If
```

and skip formatting of the textbox.

Comment: Okay, well, the function returns values correctly - nice trick to convert to double, but the formatting still doesn't display commas.  So, I put the format in the textbox properties in the format tab in the format property - just copy and paste.  Doesn't do anything.

Comment: I've tried putting a format in the format property for that field in the underlying query where the function is called, but it doesn't have any effect either.

Comment: You let the function do the formatting. See edited answer.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, in case I wanted to use the value to calculate something else.  But, okay, I tried this, and removed the format for the text box, and still no commas. It doesn't show commas in the query, either.  I think I'm going to go cry somewhere.

Comment: oh wait; I still had int() around the return value.  Now it's working!

Comment: okay, so *that* works, now how do I get it to work without putting commas in the string?  That way I can use the value to calculate with.

Comment: If you need a numeric value, return a numeric value and apply the format where you might display the value.

Comment: Oh - you mean to make the textbox use an event to format the number?  Ah, I think that could work.  It displayed the commas perfectly when the formula was part of the field in the query.  When I moved the formula to a function, that's when it stopped displaying the comma - this is the *real* problem I want to solve - getting the display to work properly without having to format the return value.  I gave you my +1 for all of your help, though.

Comment: As long as the function returns a numeric data type, the format of the textbox will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163201/discussion-between-bgmcoder-and-gustav).